# Occationally see WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED

Tags: ssh

We have a kubernetes cluster with multiple worker nodes. The only difference between the nodes are the ip addresses and hostnames. I used to ssh into all of them, and there is no problem at all.

I understand that there are a lot of similar questions related to this warning, but I don't think any of them is the same as mine. In detail, recently, this warning shows when ssh into one of the worker nodes **occationally**. That is to say, sometimes I can ssh into the machine successfully, but some times see this warning. This is the full warning message:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:95IISBgdGFLH2SEeU+E6YO+S9qnfEXfJqblNqfY/SFE.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:55
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "10.210.10.12"
RSA host key for 10.210.10.12 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

These are what I have done so far:

- Check the MAC address of the machine with `arp -a` command, and it is the targeted machine.
- Remove the 55th line of known_hosts. But after sometime, it happens again.
- Re-plug the cable, can ssh in for a while, and after sometime, it also happens again.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that you've removed the 55th line without understanding why. That line contained the previous host identification of the 10.210.10.12 machine. Why did you do that? The goal of the warning is to warn you about something suspicious, and you should aim to figure out what happened before dismissing the warning.

Checking the MAC is a good idea, but MAC addresses can be spoofed far easier than SSH host id's. It doesn't tell you much. A changed MAC would be a bad sign, but this does not tell you much. You need to figure out what happened, and so far you've found nothing.

If your company has a security team, contact them. If not, get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

After days of struggle, finall work it out. Turns out that the Supermicro motherboard will takes up an IP address for IPMI, which is also 10.210.10.12.